# Update: Function Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'get_bus_result_attribute'

Tags: oracle, function

I just think the problem of issue and change the function-to-function logic design. Then, the error as mentioned the function (get_result_attribute) - PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'get_result_attribute'. May I know the function "get_result_attribute" problem in which part?

Coding for the bus station system.

```
FUNCTION get_bus_result_attribute (iv_result_name varchar2,
                                  iv_result_key varchar2,
                                  iv_result_attribute varchar2) 
  --define the parameter to get the "sql_result" script result
    RETURN varchar2 IS


     sql_result varchar2(500);
     sql_return varchar2(500);

 BEGIN

    sql_result := 'SELECT ' || iv_result_attribute || '
                    FROM MyTable a,
                    MyTable b
           WHERE  a.bus_value_set_id = b.bus_value_set_id
             AND b.bus_value_set_name = iv_result_name
             AND a.enabled_flag = ''Y''
                 AND a.bus_value = iv_result_key
                 AND iv_result_name = get_bus_code (v_bus)
                 AND iv_result_key = get_bus_name(v_group)
                 AND iv_result_key = iv_result_attribute';

                  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_result 
                   INTO sql_return; --get the "sql_result" script result 

        return sql_return;
        exception
         when others then
           return '';
         end get_bus_result_attribute;

     FUNCTION get_bus_code (v_bus varchar2)           
       RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

         v_get_bus_code_result VARCHAR2(20)  ;

      BEGIN

          SELECT  busa.bus_code

     INTO v_get_bus_code_result

      FROM tbl_bus_code busa, tbl_bus_line busb
         WHERE  busa.bus_code_set_id = busb.bus_code_set_id
           AND busb.bus_line_set_name = 'HK_BUS_CODE'
           AND busa.enabled_flag = 'Y'
           AND (busa.attribute4 = 'Y' OR busa.attribute5 = 'Y')

           AND busa.BUS_VALUE = v_bus;

     RETURN v_get_bus_code_result;

     RETURN get_result_attribute('BUS_LINES', v_bus, 'attribute1'); /*BUS_GP*/

  EXCEPTION

     WHEN OTHERS THEN

      RETURN '';    
     END get_bus_code;     

FUNCTION get_bus_name(v_group VARCHAR2) --define the parameter and enter the value in the function 'get_bus_result_attribute'
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

  v_get_bus_div_result VARCHAR2(20)  ;    

   BEGIN

         SELECT DISTINCT CASE busa.bus_code  --Bus code
                    WHEN '52'    THEN '52X'   
                    WHEN '58P'    THEN '58'
                    WHEN 'K1'  THEN 'K1C'
                    WHEN '40'    THEN '40X'
                    WHEN '6'    THEN '6X'
                    WHEN '7'    THEN '7'
                    WHEN '58M'    THEN '58'

              ELSE ''
          END bus_code   --Bus code           

      INTO v_get_bus_div_result

     FROM tbl_bus_code busa, tbl_bus_line busb

     WHERE busa.bus_code_set_id = busb.bus_code_set_id
        AND busb.bus_line_set_name = 'HK_BUS_LINES'
       AND busa.enabled_flag = 'Y'
       AND (busa.attribute4 = 'Y' OR busa.attribute5 = 'Y')
       AND busa.bus_code NOT IN ('INACTIVE', 'XXX')
       AND get_bus_code(busa.BUS_VALUE) = v_group

      RETURN get_result_attribute('BUS_GROUP', v_group, 'attribute2');
                                                        --bus_group_dir 

     EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RETURN '';
    END get_bus_name;  


FUNCTION BUS_DOC_TEXT (N_ID NUMBER, N_HEAD_ID NUMBER) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

   v_bus_doc_text VARCHAR2(150); 

   BEGIN

SELECT 'BUS\' 
      || get_bus_result_attribute(abc.attribute14) 
      || '\' 
      || abc.attribute14 
      || '\' 
      || abc.segment1

    INTO v_bus_doc_text

     FROM my_table_c abc

        WHERE abc.ORG_ID = N_ID          -- parameter
          AND abc.bus_id = N_HEADER_ID;      -- parameter

  END;


  RETURN v_bus_doc_text ;

   END;

  END;
```

Comment: I dont think you can save the EXECUTE result in a variable And  definitly not in a string

Comment: There shouldn't be semicolon after `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_result` if you want to return the result . The syntax should be `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  query_var INTO result_var;`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I change the script as "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_result INTO sql_return;"

Comment: Then, program is still to mentione the error as function  (get_bus_code) - Encountered the symbol "get_bus_code". May I know need to enter the function (get_result_attribute) parameter in the function  (get_bus_code) delcaration ?

Comment: Are those functions supposed to be separate ones, or did you mean to declare functions within a function? If latter, move them into main function's DECLARE section. If former, there are some ENDs missing (by the way, you should END a procedure with its name; it makes code clearer and easier to read, e.g. `end get_bus_name;`

Comment: hi Little. I just to revise the script and add the declare of parameters in the function. correct ? Then, the error to mention the function (BUS_DOC_TEXT). Is this syntax issue?

Comment: Your formatting is all over the shop at the moment so it's difficult to see what's going on where. First thing I noticed is that you have a semicolon (`;`) embedded in the middle of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, which includes the USING clause.

Comment: I've edited the question *just to fix the tab formatting*. This reveals a number of issues, one of which is that your initial DECLARE is ended prematurely (just before the declaration of function BUS_DOC_TEXT). After that function there is a dangling RETURN statement followed by two additional "END"s.

Comment: Side note: don't use "when others" to swallow exceptions. These are bugs waiting to happen.

Comment: Yes. when I remove the "when other" exception. The issue is still to show the function (BUS_DOC_TEXT) error: Encountered the symbol "BUS_DOC_TEXT" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;

Comment: Any member can help me to identify the function issue? Thank You!